# different type of error with arrayList and array of Object

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections

I create an `ArrayList` and an array of object from class `Student` and `Student` class isn't instanceof `Comparable` interface, so when I write my code with `ArrayList` this causes a compile error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList <Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
     studentList.add(new Student("Ahmed",50));
     studentList.add(new Student("Ameen",30));

     java.util.Collections.sort(studentList);
     System.out.println(studentList);

}
  }

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    Student ( String name , int score){
        this.name= name;
        this.score = score;   
    }
}
```

and when I write my code with array of object this cause run time error

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Student [] student = new Student[2];
      student[0]=new Student("Ahmed",50);
      student[1]=new Student("Ameen",30);
     java.util.Arrays.sort(student);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(student));
}
}

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;
    Student ( String name , int score){
        this.name= name;
        this.score = score;   
    }}
```

My question is why do I get a compile error with array list, and why do I get a run time error with array of object? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList is generic Class and the key benefit of generics is to enable errors to be detected at compile time rather than at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you get a compile time error on line

```
java.util.Collections.sort(studentList);
```

`studentList` does not satisfy the parameter definition of the method `sort`. Look at the signature of `sort`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

`sort` expects a `List<T>` where the generic type `T` is extending the interface `Comparable`. The class `Student` doesn't implement `Comparable` in anyway. Thus `studentList` cannot be sorted using `Collections.sort`.

On the other site we have the `Arrays` method

```
public static void sort(Object[] a)
```

This method doesn't require more than an object array. The array `student` fits, so no compile time error. But under the hood also this method assumes that the objects in the array are kind of `Comparable`. Let'a have a look at the exception's stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: playground.Example$Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:316)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:184)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1244)
    at playground.Example.main(Example.java:20)
```

As we see `countRunAndMakeAscending`casts a `Student` instance to `Comparable` and this fails. The cause is the same as above.

There at least two ways to solve this:

a) Let `Student` implement `Comparable` - preferably like this:

```
  public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    Student(String name, int score) {
      this.name = name;
      this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
      // implement comparision by name and score for exmaple
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

You have to implement the method `compareTo(Student o)` according to your needs. This will work for the list `studentList` and for the array `student`.

b) Use `java.util.Collections.sort(studentList, comparator)`. This way `Student` doesn't need to implement `Comparable` by it's own. Instead of this you can provide a `Comparator<Student>` which will compare the students. Moreover you can use different comparators with the same `studentList`.